# How validation date to not less than the start date in textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have 2 date:

start date

```
<input type="text" name="startdate" value="2016-04-08">
```

End date

```
<input type="text" name="enddate" value="2016-09-02">
```

but how to use javascript to validate days of the end date to not less than the days from start date.

like

```
startdate '08' = end date '02' and 'not ok'
or
startdate '08' = end date '08' and 'ok'
```

thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have to compare the days, all you have to do is checking if one value is equal to, or higher than the other.

You can accomplish this by getting both values, take the last part, and compare those. For example:

```
var date = '2016-04-08';
var day = date.split('-')[2];
```

`split` turns the string into an array: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

The last value is the day. If you want to compare it as a number, make sure to turn it into a number (or `int`): [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oqvjt1k3/)**

If you want to compare the whole date, which makes more sense IMO, it's a bit more tricky. In that case you have to turn the values into proper JS `Date` objects. Once they are both `Date` objects, you can compare them.

For this you can also use the `split` part as above. Provide the three parts (year, month, day) to the `Date` object to create a valid date object.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/186c037b/)**

Comment: Please don't post code elsewhere, links rot. Post it here as a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like these,

```
function CheckSchedulingDates() {
  var SD = document.getElementById('startdate').value;
  var ED = document.getElementById('enddate').value;
  if (Date.parse(SD) >= Date.parse(ED)) {
    return 'The ending date must occur after the starting date.'    
  }
}
```

Comment: No, don't use *Date.parse*, see [*How to get correct Data object from string in JavaScript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488639/how-to-get-correct-data-object-from-string-in-javascript/36489088#36489088).